# Error displaying current date struts

Tags: java

I want to display current date in my textbox but it doesn’t work
I am working with the framework struts
this is my code jsp

```
 <html:text  value="<%= new java.util.Date() %>" property="date"</html:text>
```

Comment: try `<html:text  value="<%= new java.util.Date() %>" property="date" />`

Comment: i stil have the same error 'The method setValue(String) in the type BaseInputTag is not applicable for the arguments (Date)"

Comment: hava a look here: http://www.mkyong.com/struts2/struts-2-date-tag-example/

Comment: this is helpful ! but I want to display it in textbox